# Problema a la hora de retornar un array con otros dos arrays dentro a la función principal

Tags: c++, array

Resulta que intento hacer un programa de prueba que te devuelva dos arrays (Impares, Pares) a la función principal desde otra función. Mi duda recae en cómo devolver esos dos arrays. En un principio pensé en ponerlos dentro de uno solo en forma de punteros y devolver el puntero del array que engloba a esos dos y luego acceder a los arrays individualmente mediante 'Arr' (posición 0) y 'Arr+1' (posición 1), lo hice así pero los resultados no dan:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *Prueba(){
    int *Pares;
    int *Impares;
    static int ArrayPares[5]={2,4,6,8,10};
    static int ArrayImpares[5]={1,3,5,7,9};

    Pares=ArrayPares;
    Impares=ArrayImpares;

    static int *ArrayFinal[2]={Pares, Impares};


    return *ArrayFinal;
}

int main(){
    int *Arr, *Par, *Impar;

    Arr=Prueba();
    Par=Arr;     //accediendo a la posición 0 de ArrayFinal (Pares)
    Impar=Arr+1; //accediendo a la posición 1 de ArrayFinal (Impares)

    cout<<Par[0]; cout<<endl; //aquí debería mostrar 2, que lo muestra bien
    cout<<Impar[0];           //aquí debería mostrar 1, pero en su lugar muestra 4

    return 0;
}
```

Espero que se haya entendido la pregunta, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu función no retorna un puntero a `int`, sino un puntero a un array que contiene dos punteros a `int`.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo resolverías en código? Porque así escrito no lo entiendo mucho. Gracias.

Comment: Lo explico mejor en la respuesta que acabo de añadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has declarado la función como `int *`. Entonces debería retornar un puntero a `int` (o un la dirección de un array de `int`, que es lo mismo para el C).

En cambio quieres retornar un array de punteros a `int`. Por tanto en el fondo un puntero a una dirección donde está ese array, cuyos contenidos son punteros. O sea, un puntero a puntero.

La función entonces sería así:

```
int **Prueba(){
    int *Pares;
    int *Impares;
    static int ArrayPares[5]={2,4,6,8,10};
    static int ArrayImpares[5]={1,3,5,7,9};

    Pares=ArrayPares;
    Impares=ArrayImpares;

    static int *ArrayFinal[2]={Pares, Impares};


    return ArrayFinal;
}
```

Observa también el `return`. No hay que poner un `*` delante porque lo que quieres retonar es el array completo, mientras `*ArrayFinal` retonaría solo el valor de su primer elemento (o sea, el primer puntero).

También cambia la forma en que hay que usarlo desde `main`, ya que la variable `Arr` en que recibes el resultado ha de ser también un puntero a puntero (mientras que las variables `Par` e `Impar`, esas sí, serían punteros a entero). Es decir:

```
int main(){
    int **Arr, *Par, *Impar;

    Arr=Prueba();
    Par=*Arr;     //accediendo a la posición 0 de ArrayFinal (Pares)
    Impar=*(Arr+1); //accediendo a la posición 1 de ArrayFinal (Impares)

    cout<<Par[0]; cout<<endl; //aquí debería mostrar 2, que lo muestra bien
    cout<<Impar[0];           //aquí debería mostrar 1, pero en su lugar muestra 4

    return 0;
}
```

Por cierto que la farragosa sintaxis usada en `main()` puede escribirse también de la siguiente forma, más amigable (pero más confusa si no tienes muy clara la relación entre punteros y arrays del C):

```
    int **Arr, *Par, *Impar;

    Arr=Prueba();
    Par=Arr[0];    //accediendo a la posición 0 de ArrayFinal (Pares)
    Impar=Arr[1];  //accediendo a la posición 1 de ArrayFinal (Impares)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, llevaba un rato comiéndome la cabeza con esto!!

Answer (score 1):

Hay formas mucho mas sencillas de trabajar con ese tipo de cosas, y, en C++, es *trivial* el hacerlo: usa una `struct` auxiliar:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ArrOf2Ptr {
  ArrOf2Ptr( int *p1, int *p2 ) : pares( p1 ), impares( p2 ) { }
  int *pares;
  int *impares;
};

ArrOf2Ptr Prueba( ) {
  static int Pares[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
  static int Impares[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

  return ArrOf2Ptr{ Pares, Impares };
}

int main( ) {
  ArrOf2Ptr result = Prueba( );

  std::cout << *result.pares << '\n' << *result.impares << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

El tamaño ocupado por la `struct` es el mismo que el ocupado por la formación de punteros original. El rendimiento es exactamente igual. Pero el código resultante es mucho mas *amigable* y mantenible.

Comment: El compilador suelta un error en el primer punto de  ``.pares = Pares, .impares = Impares ``. (Se esperaba una expresión)

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, lo único comentar que, si no me equivoco, las estructuras se retornan por copia, y no por referencia. En este caso en que la estructura tiene solo un par de elementos no hay problema, pero si tuviera muchos sería más eficiente retornar un puntero a la estructura en lugar de la propia estructura.

Comment: @Sify Es en C++20, lo siento por no indicarlo en la respuesta, no me di cuenta. Para inferiores hay que añadir un constructor. He editado la respuesta para que soporte C++11.

Comment: @abulafia Cierto, se devuelve por copia. Asi haría yo este caso concreto de tener que hacerlo. Si tuvieran mas elementos ... pues ya se vería, depende. Por cierto, te me has adelantado con tu respuesta por 30 segundos. Tuve que reescribirla completa :-(